# Floating Action Button and RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to show Floating Action Button when all RecyclerView items fit screen. The problem is  - when Floating Action Button is hidden and RecyclerView becomes almost empty - there is no place to scroll and so Floating Action Button not shown.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you have to use co-ordinate layout like this
 https://lab.getbase.com/introduction-to-coordinator-layout-on-android/

Comment: Please, add some code sample to the answer, as this might be considered a link only answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the desired behavior by using a Coordinator Layout. The below links are pretty good references to start with.

1. https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling(part3)/
2. https://medium.com/ribot-labs/exploring-the-new-android-design-support-library-b7cda56d2c32

Comment: Please, add some code sample to the answer, as this might be considered a link only answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem in such way:

1. Adding RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver to adapter
2. After data have changed I am registering `ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener` on recyclerView

   `private RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver adapterDataObserver = new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
       @Override
       public void onChanged() {
           super.onChanged();
            recyclerViewEmptySupport.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onPreDraw() {
               recyclerViewEmptySupport.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
               scrollingFABBehavior.recyclerViewChanged(recyclerViewEmptySupport, dialogsListAdapter, fab);
               return false;
           }
       });
       }
   };`
3. In this listener I inform FAB that recyclerView **MAY** be empty enough (or may be not) to forcely be shown